# What is the circle-equivariant cohomology of the real projective plane

Tags: at.algebraic-topology, equivariant-cohomology

Let P denote the real projective plane. It has an action of the circle group S<sup>1</sup>. (e.g. Let S<sup>1</sup> act on the 2-sphere by rotations about an axis, then this action descends to the quotient P). I have a simple question.

What is the equivariant cohomology $H^\ast_{S^1}(P;\mathbb{F}_2)$?

Ideally I want a description as a module over $H^\ast_{S^1}(\mathrm{pt};\mathbb{F}_2)$, but I can't even manage to compute the structure as an abelian group myself.

Comment: Do you mean the cohomology of the Borel construction?

Comment: Yes (what other options are there?)

Comment: Have you tried writing down an $S^1$-cell structure for $P$ ? There is a very simple one for $S^2$, and you can modify it appropriately to get one on $P$, which should give you a description over the cohomology of the point (regardless of whether you mean Borel or Bredon cohomology)

Answer (score 11):

I think one gets
$$H^*_{S^1}(\mathbb{RP}^2; \mathbb{F}_2) = \mathbb{F}_2[x, y]/(xy) $$
where $|x|=1$ and $|y|=2$. The module structure over $H^*_{S^1}(pt; \mathbb{F}_2) = \mathbb{F}_2[t]$ is given by $t \mapsto x^2 + y$.

I got this by writing $\mathbb{RP}^2$ as the union of $\mathbb{RP}^1$ equipped with the "double speed" action of $S^1$, and $D^2$ equipped with the natural action of $S^1$. The corresponding pushout of Borel constructions takes the form
$$BC_2 \leftarrow pt \to BS^1$$
as spaces over $BS^1$, which gives the claimed formula.